Are cage graphs Hamiltonian?
An $(r, g)$-cage graph is an $r$-regular graph with the least amount of vertices having girth $g$. While looking up examples of cage graphs I couldn't help myself but noticing they all seem to be Hamiltonian, with the exception of the Petersen graph.
The Wikipedia article on cage graphs list the following as notable examples:

and in fact, all of them but the Petersen graph are Hamiltonian (you can clearly see this in they're particular articles as their main diagram have their vertices arranged in one big circle). The $(r, 3)$ and $(r, 4)$-cages are $K_r$ and $K_{r,r}$, respectively, both of which are clearly Hamiltonian for $r\ge 3$ (notice cage graphs only exist for $r\ge3$). Also, cage graphs are not necessarily unique for a fixed pair $(r, g)$ and there are three $(3, 10)$-cages, the Balaban 10-cage, the Harries graph and the Harries–Wong graph (as listed by Wikipedia), all of them Hamiltonian.
I looked upon some more examples and decided that was enough evidence gathering, so now I wonder how should one proceed about proving this. The amount of vertices in an $(r, g)$-cage is much larger than $r$ or $g$ in general (this is a theorem) so Bondy–Chvátal Theorem does not apply.
This question has been asked before here, but it was also asking about a second (and also very interesting) conjecture on cage graphs and hasn't got much attention. This might be an open problem as far as I know, but I haven't seen anyone proposing it beyond the previous post.

Update: The paper The smallest cubic graphs of girth nine (access here) lists every single one of the $18$ $(3, 9)$-cages and notices they are all Hamiltonian.
